# Changing the type of an entity preserving its ID

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am using hibernate as a persistence layer. There are 2 entities that live in the same table extending one superclass with single table inheritance strategy.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    // some common fields for B and C
}


@Entity
public class B extends A {
    // B-specific fields
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
    // C-specific fields
}
```

I have an instance of B with id=4. How do I change the type of this instance to C preserving it's ID (4)?

```
B b = em.find(B.class, 4L);
C c = convertToC(b);
c.setId(b.getId());
em.remove(b);
em.persist(c);
```

The code above fails with

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: C
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I have added the exception to the question

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you tried calling merge() instead of persist()?

Comment: Yeah, merge gives c a new id.

Comment: This may be an example of the inadequacy of the Entitymanager API. It's not as expressive as the native Hibernate API, and sometimes makes rather less sense.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the native Hibernate API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hibernate attempts to make persistence as transparent as it possibly can - which means it tries to follow the same principles as normal Java objects. Now, rephrasing your question in Java, you'd get:

> How can I convert an instance of B class into an instance of (incompatible) C class?

And you know the answer to that - you can't. You can create a **new** instance of C and copy necessary attributes, but B will *always* be B, never C. Thus the answer to your original question is - it cannot be done via JPA or Hibernate API.

However, unlike plain Java, with Hibernate you can cheat :-) `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` is  mapped using `@DiscriminatorColumn` and in order to convert B into C you need to update its value from whatever's specified for B into whatever's specified for C. The trick is - you cannot do it using Hibernate API; you need to do it via plain SQL. You can, however, map this update statement as named SQL query and execute it using Hibernate facilities.

The algorithm, therefore, is:

1. **Evict** B from session if it's there (this is important)
2. Execute your named query.
3. Load what-is-now-known-as-C using former B's id.
4. Update / set attributes as needed.
5. Persist C

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "c" is an object which the hibernate session knows nothing about, but it has an ID, so it assumes that the object has already been persisted. In that context, persist() makes no sense, and so it fails.

The javadoc for Hibernate Session.persist() (I know you're not using the Hibernate API, but the semantics are the same, and the hibernate docs are better) says "Make a transient instance persistent". If your object already has an ID, it's not transient. Instead, it thinks it's a detached instance (i.e. an instance that has been persisted, but is not associated with the current session).

I suggest you try merge() instead of persist().

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason of the exception, I'll mind that. Merge doesn't fail, but gives "c" a new id, ignoring what has been set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own id (not generated) and do the following:

1. Retrive B
2. open transaction
3. delete B
4. commit the transaction
5. open a new transaction
6. create C and persist it
7. Close the second transaction

In this way you will clear the id from the table before re-inserting it as C.

Comment: That would be quite hard to implement. All my entities use autoincremented ids. Is there a way to force the value of a generated id?

Answer (score 0):

How do you distinguish between the two entities in the table? I assume that there some field value (or values) that you can change to make B into a C?

You could have a method where you load the super-class A and change the distinguishing values and save. Then in your next Hibernate Session your B will be a C.

Comment: Hibernate uses discriminator column to determine which class it needs to instantiate when loading data. The value of the column is equal to the simple name of the class.

Do you suggest using plain SQL to modify the table data? I don't see another way to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think skaffman is right here, once the id has been set it won't persist, and further because the id is generated it expects the sequence to be in charge of assigning the id number.

You could possibly not put the id as @GeneratedValue? or one of the different generator strategy types maybe to avoid the merge generating a new sequence value, but I suspect that would be problematic.