# How to insert multiple child entities to the same parent with JPA inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, inheritance

Basically I have a similar issue as in this question:
[jpa how to create new entity with same id as parent entity (JOINED Inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354037/jpa-how-to-create-new-entity-with-same-id-as-parent-entity-joined-inheritance)

But since that question is 9 years old, here is me hoping that today there is a solution to this problem.

Here is my Problem:
I am using entity inheritance with inheritance type joined.

The entities are:
1. Person
2. Doctor (extends Person)
3. Professor (extends Person)

**Here is my actual issue:**

- When I create a Doctor, the data is filled in tables Doctor and Person with the same id, lets say id = 1 ==>  All is good so far
- When I create a Professor, the data is filled in tables Professor and Person with the same id, lets say id = 2 ==> All still good so far
- When an existing Doctor (id=1) now also becomes a Professor (or vice versa), I want the Person and Doctor to persist with the same id, and just add the entry in the table Professor, also with id=1.

Here is some code of how I try to make a Doctor also a Professor:

```
public void makeDocAlsoProf(id){

// Find existing Person
List<Person> persons = personRepo.findById(id);
Person foundPerson = !persons.isEmpty() ? persons.iterator().next() : null;

prof = new Professor(foundPerson); //This copies all parent Person fields
prof.setId(foundPerson.getId()); // Set the same id (id = 1)

prof = professorRepo.save(prof); // This gives Prof a new id (id = 3)
}
```

**So before the execution of the method this is what rows I have in the database:**

Person:

- id 1
- id 2

Doctor:

- id 1

Professor:

- id 2

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

Person:

- id 1
- id 2

Doctor:

- id 1

Professor:

- id 1
- id 2

**Here is what I get:**

Person:

- id 1
- id 2
- id 3 (same values as 1)

Doctor:

- id 1

Professor:

- id 2
- id 3

I would appreciate any help, even if that is not possible maybe a hint on how to solve this using a different entity model approach or something else.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: can you put your model code?

Comment: So basically your mapping is: a person can be also a doctor and a professor. May you post the models source?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is more of a role-model than inheritance. Is there a reason you don't assign roles to a person, like:

```
class Person {

  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

The flavour of `@ManyToMany` of course depends on the nature of `Role` - whether it's an Enum or a regular object itself.

Besides that: What's the reason you care for IDs yourself and don't let the database handle that, preferrably using a sequence generator? You should rather use foreign keys instead of copying object attributes and probably identify persons by their `@NaturalId` like e-mail address etc.