# Hibernate inheritence problem on merge with same id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a problem that I can not resolve. Let's say I have an entity with definition;

```
@Table(name = "person")
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    protected String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    //getters setters contsructer
}
```

I have another class which extend person lets say

```
@Table(name = "special_person")
@Entity(name = "SpecialPerson")
public class SpecialPerson extends Person {
    @Column
    private String specialValue;
    //getters setters contsructer
}
```

Now I create a person and save it

```
Person person = new Person("John", "Doe");
String recordedId = entityManager.merge(person).getId();
```

After saving it, I create a special person with recorded id and saving it,

```
Person sPerson = new SpecialPerson(recordedId, "John", "Doe", "Special One");
entityManager.merge(sPerson);
```

I expect, hibenate identifies it has a parent and only create a record in special_person table with recodedId but intead of this, hibernate give another id to sPerson and creates new records for person and special_person table. What is the reason of this and how can I handle with this situation.

**UPDATE**
This is a duplicate. I found it just now. Sorry for any inconvenience. For answer please visit: [jpa how to create new entity with same id as parent entity (JOINED Inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354037/jpa-how-to-create-new-entity-with-same-id-as-parent-entity-joined-inheritance/1354466)

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. If you create a new Person, it cannot have the same ID as an already existing Person. Why it generates a new ID, I don't know (I suspect it's a bug in your code), but this should throw an exception. You can not change the type of an entity. If you want to do that, then don't use inheritance. Instead, use composition: a person has a role "special person".

Comment: Why wrong. It is a person too.