# Hibernate Java persist a subclass entity from persisted superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Agent class and a User class which extends Agent.
I would like to cast a persisted Agent to a User and persist the user using the same id, name and firstname. I don't what to insert an other line into Agent table. How can I do that ?

Here are my classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Agent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "fistname", nullable = false)
    protected String fistname;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public User extends Agent{
   @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
   public String login;
   @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
   public String password;
```

I would like to do that

```
Agent agent=agentService.findOne(1);
User user = new User(agent);
user.setLogin("login");
...
user=userService.saveAndFlush(user);
ok = user.getId() == agent.getId();
```

To sum up I'd like to grant an Agent to a User when I need it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.Be specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the type of an entity preserving its ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118873/changing-the-type-of-an-entity-preserving-its-id)

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an Agent to a User, but you can build a user from an Agent by setting the Agent's properties in the User propeties, unless you have added a copy constructor from Agent ->User in the User class, in both cases a new User will be created and a new row will be added.

Comment: I already have a copy constructor but it doesn't use the same person in fact it insert an other person when I use saveAndFlush

Comment: Yes because you're creating a new User object in this case, it will always create a new User, I think that you should use composition in this case and not inheritance, this says that your class Agent will have a class member of type Agent and won't extend Agent any more, Am I clear ?

Comment: Yeah thanks but I've already think about it I wanted to know if it's possible to do what I want with Hibernate.

Comment: Ofcourse you can using composition, check the details in this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component)

Comment: I don't understand how composition helps me. Sorry I didn't get what you've said I thought It was just remove the extends in User and add Agent column in User

Answer (score 0):

I've tought doing this. It's working but I lose the fact that a user is a specialized Agent.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Agent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "fistname", nullable = false)
    protected String fistname;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   protected Integer id;
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_agent",nullable = false)
   protected Agent agent;
   @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String login;
   @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
   private String password;
```